# CPU profiling tools for Java?

Tags: java, profiling

I'd like to benchmark different libraries to see which one suits my needs best. This useful program should be able to tell me how much processing power I use to run a particular thread (This is what matters the most).

Other functionality (RAM usage and other) would be nice but are not needed. Also, it would be awesome if is free and open-source.

I use Eclipse.

Thanks.